# How to open videofile in native resolution?

Tags: display, video, resolution

I have MacBook with `15,4-inch (2880 x 1800)` display and for example I have video file for which
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4` shows me
`Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2100x678, 961 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)`

Is it possible to open videofile of size `2100x678` on screen with resolution `2880x1800` without resize\rescale? i.e. I want pixel size of video match pixel size on screen.

Comment: What have you tried, with which applicatio have you opened it?

Comment: I open it with `QuickTime Player Version 10.5 (1015.2.1)`, I'm not sure how test if video is opened in native resolution.